# React conceptual problem : An interval which triggers a timeout

Tags: reactjs

Imagine this structure in **pseudo** React code :

```
export const App = () => {

    const onTick = () => {
        //? (continue reading)
    }

    return (
    <Root>
       <Ticker onTick={onTick}/>
       <UIComponent mustTick={?}/>
    </Root>
    );
}
```

Without detailing, **Ticker** contains a system of setInterval/clearInterval that guarantees that "ontick" is called every 5 seconds. So far so good.

What I want is **UIComponent** to display a message every time a tick happens, but only for one second. Then hide the message again until the next tick.

This is easily achieved inside UIComponent with a setTimeout

(still in **pseudo-code** )

```
export const UIComponent = (mustTick : boolean) => {
    const [messageVisible, setMessageVisible] = useState(false);
    //Also store timeout in state (not detailed)

    const onTimeoutFinished = useCallback(() => {
          //clear timeout (not detailed)
          setMessageVisible(false);
       }, 
       [setMessageVisible]
    );

    useEffect(() => {
         if(mustTick && !messageVisible) {
            setMessageVisible(true);
            setTimeout(1000ms, onTimeoutFinished);
         }
      }, 
      [mustTick, messageVisible]);

      return messageVisible? (<>Message</>) : (<></>);
}
```

**MY PROBLEM :** The part that I don't know how to manage is to communicate the tick only as an **impulse** to UIComponent. I'm not sure how to avoid heavy wiring to manage it going back to false instantly after becoming true, and who should do it.

How I do it at the moment :
(still in **pseudo-code** )

```
export const App = () => {

    const [mustTick, setMustTick] = useState(false);

    const onTick = useCallback(() => {
        setMustTick(true);
    },
    [setMustTick]);

    const onTickProcessed = useCallback(() => {
        setMustTick(false);
    },
    [setMustTick]);

    return (
    <Root>
       <Ticker onTick={onTick}/>
       <UIComponent mustTick={mustTick} onTickProcessed/>
    </Root>
    );
}
```

I hate that the parent ("App") has to manage that boolean, and in such a verbose way.

Isn't there a better way to keep the state management in the children as much as possible? the children really have a very different purpose, and UIComponent will even probably be disabled in Prod :
**Ticker** is really all about doing something internally at every tick, while **UIComponent** is really all about flashing a message briefly at every tick, for informing the user.

Comment: If `UIComponent` being shown on screen is governed entirely by the state of `Ticker`, would it make sense in your situation to have it as a child component? Then a single interval inside `Ticker` could control the show/hide (A single 1 second interval could check if it was the 5th second, as well as hiding 1 second later) and you wouldn't need to pass props upwards.

Comment: Do you mean a child component of Ticker? I don't think it's an easy solution: Ticker is in reality a whole tree of components that is the "real" app (Prod and Dev), while UIComponent is a separate tree structure of components (displayed somewhere else on screen, and therefore pretty far in the DOM) that is shown only in Dev. A developer's toolbar if you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to "teleport" an impulse from one are of the code to another (in this case : make the callback accessible anywhere) will be to manage the tick at top level and transform it into a React **Context**. Then make UIComponent consume the context.